# Importing rdf/xml in Apache Jena: Lower case preferred exception

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I'm trying to import an RDF/XML file with Apache Jena using the following code from the tutorial:

```
Path input = Paths.get("C:\Users\Admin\Documents");
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel() ; 
model.read(input+File.separator+"foaf.rdf", "RDF/XML") ;
```

The file being imported is [here](https://raw.github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/master/examples/foaf.rdf).

When I run the test code, the following exception is returned:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: <C:\Users\Admin\Documents\foaf.rdf> 
  Code: 11/LOWERCASE_PREFERRED in SCHEME: 
    lowercase is preferred in this component
```

The message is really useful and self-explanatory! 
However, do you have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that it's expecting a URI, not a file name. It's treating C:... as an (unknown) URI scheme 'C'.

Try the following instead:

```
Path input = Paths.get("C:\Users\Admin\Documents", "foaf.rdf");
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel() ; 
model.read(input.toUri().toString(), "RDF/XML") ;
```

Comment: This solution is better. I'm sorry to move my accepted answer from the previous one to yours, but I have to do it for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what apache jena is or does but you could try lowercasing "c:" but this probably won't work so you could try

```
file:/c:/my/path
```

Comment: Just a little feedback: lowercasing worked, i.e. it removed the problem that I mentioned and returned another exception (`UNWISE_CHARACTER`). Than I used `c:/my/path` and everything worked good.